How to find out persistant SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors value in MySQL
How to find out persistant SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors value in MySQL
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connect_errors';

Based on the contents of the questions 2 things come to mind. 1. There is no clear question. 2. What does this have to do with Ubuntu? You do not have any info that suggests it is Ubuntu related.

So long as your MySQL account has sufficient privileges, you can use the following command to view the current maximums for connection-based variables:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max%connect%'

This will give you something like:
| Variable_name        | Value |
|----------------------|-------|
| max_connect_errors   | 100   |
| max_connections      | 151   |
| max_user_connections | 0     |

Note: 0 means "unlimited", which will then be constrained by the max_connections setting.
If you plan on changing any of these values, the following syntax is used:
SET GLOBAL {variable}={value};

For your question, this would be something like:
SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=250;

However, it will first be important to identify why there are so many connection errors. If the problem is happening on a bare metal (or VM) installation of Ubuntu, it will be important to see if the connection string is using IP addresses or domain names, as there could be name resolution issues. If the problem is happening on Amazon RDS, then the above solution will not work at all, as Amazon handles these variables differently.
